# Getting 'MissingMethodException' when trying to use 'dnx . ef migration add' in EF7 beta6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to play around with ASP.NET 5 beta5 and Entity Framework 7 beta6 in Visual Studio 2015 RTM. The problem is I cannot get them to run together even by exactly following guides like this:
http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5.html

In this example, when I reach the part that I need to run this command:

```
dnx . ef migration add MyFirstMigration
```

I always get this error:

```
Using context 'BloggingContext'.
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.TryAdd(Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor)'.
```

I tried and retried all the steps and searched for anything I may have missed in my project with no luck.

Comment: I somehow find the problem to be in different beta versions of references in 'project.json'. Some of them where beta5 and some beta6. But I cannot figure out why when I create a new ASP.NET project, default references end-up being added from two different beta versions. Working on that.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably because you're using an incorrect (or just buggy) version of the Dot Net Virtual Machine. Try running `dnvm list` to see which versions you have installed and which one is set to active, then you may need to run `dnvm use ...` to switch versions.

For example, I run `dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1` for many of my .csproj apps.